# Install my own superuser page

Tags: discussion

I work in a small startup and now is the time for creating the company's culture. Having been using superuser/stackoverflow/serverfault for a while now, it is clear to me how awesome these sites are for sharing knowledge, and hey, *I want one* ;)

I was wondering if the superuser/* sites are based in any open/free projects I could implement in my own servers to help us managing our knowledge base.

I know, I know, there are plenty of free systems out there to that end. We already have a Wiki, support page, etc. I'm asking if is it possible to have my own *superuser like page*. I think this would be perfect to share products and proprietary technology knowledge among employees as the company grows.

Comment: For info about the engine itself check our [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with) post on meta.stackoverflow. As far as I know it is *not* open source, and there are not plans for it to become so, but I do believe there are some clones about (again, check the meta sites, there's some post about but I don't have one to hand). This question actually belongs on meta, so I've voting to migrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is far the best shot:

[Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

cheers,

f.

ps.: Can't I mark answer nor comment my own questions? o.O

Comment: if you go login over at the parent Super User site(http://superuser.com) your accounts should be automatically associated so you can take "ownership" of your original question and edit it/accept an answer.  If the association is not automatic, you can click on your name at the top of the page and use the "Accounts" tab to do it manually.

Comment: Hm.. nope.. it didn't work. I'm currently logged in in all pages (and my profile seems correctly associated in all of them), but I still have no ownership of this question :(

Answer (score 2):

The only official way to get this is by proposing [an Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com)

Given that you probably won't get enough followers (with sufficient rep) to reach Beta through that, your only options are the open source alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You could try [shapado](http://shapado.com/) .
Anyone can create a qa site in 8 seconds for free.